# adding dropout in tensorflow causes incorrect result?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I use tensorflow and python to predict the stock price in a demo. But when i add dropout to the code, the generated figure doesnt seem to be correct. Please advise where is wrong.

```
with tf.variable_scope(scope_name):
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_inputs)
    lstm_dropout = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell,input_keep_prob=1.0, output_keep_prob=1.0)
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout]*num_layers)
    output, state = tf.nn.rnn(cell, input, dtype=tf.float32)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use dropout when making predictions. Only use it during training.

Comment: any example to add dropout in training?

Answer (score 1):

You should only apply dropout in training, but not in inference.

You can do this by pass the dropout probability by a placeholder.

Then set the keep probability to one when inference.

As your example :

```
input_keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
output_keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
with tf.variable_scope(scope_name):
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=n_inputs)
    lstm_dropout = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell,input_keep_prob=input_keep_prob, 
        output_keep_prob=output_keep_prob)
    cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout]*num_layers)
    output, state = tf.nn.rnn(cell, input, dtype=tf.float32) 
#setup your loss and training optimizer
#y_pred = .....
#loss = .....
#train_op = .....

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={input_keep_prob=0.7, output_keep_prob=0.7}) #set dropout when training
    y = sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={input_keep_prob=1.0, output_keep_prob=1.0}) #retrieve the prediction without dropout when inference
```